# Segmentation fault(core dumped) -ROS error

Tags: c++, class, mutex, ros

Trying to write a cpp code to print out messages from camera image using darknet. I built a class in which there is mutex method which I use for utilizing callback message in multiple threads. Although catkin_make builds the file successfully, it gives segmentation error when I run the ros command with **rosrun** . The code is as follows:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "darknet_ros_msgs/BoundingBoxes.h"
#include "darknet_ros_msgs/BoundingBox.h"

#include<string>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>

#include <mutex>
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

class Firstolo
{
private:
    std::mutex yolo_mtx;
    darknet_ros_msgs::BoundingBoxes last_yolo_msg;
    
public:
    void callback(const darknet_ros_msgs::BoundingBoxes& msg)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(yolo_mtx);
        last_yolo_msg = msg; 
    }

    const darknet_ros_msgs::BoundingBoxes getYoloLastMsg()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(yolo_mtx);
        return last_yolo_msg;
    }

    void dothejob()
    {
        std:: cout << "Here it goes: " << getYoloLastMsg().bounding_boxes[0].xmin << std::endl;
        std:: cout << "Here it goes: " << getYoloLastMsg().bounding_boxes[0].xmax << std::endl;
        std:: cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H"; 
    }

    Firstolo()
    {
    }
    Firstolo(Firstolo&)
    {
    std::mutex yolo_mtx;
    }
    ~Firstolo()
    {
    }
};

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc,argv,"cood_subscriber");
Firstolo nc;
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Subscriber sub;
sub = nh.subscribe("/darknet_ros/bounding_boxes", 100, &Firstolo::callback, &nc);

nc.dothejob();
ros::spin();
return 0;
}
```

Edit: It turns out that the problem is in the **void dothejob()**. I added **std::lock_guardstd::mutex lck(yolo_mtx);** to the **void dothejob()** and Segmentation error no longer shows up. Now the only remaining problem is that **std:: cout << "Here it goes: " << getYoloLastMsg().bounding_boxes[0].xmin << std::endl;** line keeps waiting for messages rather than printing them out. In fact, messages naturally should appear since there is darknet running in the background and generating messages.

Comment: Honestly very little knowledge about this, but isn't the following better `const darknet_ros_msgs::BoundingBoxes getYoloLastMsg() { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(yolo_mtx); auto tmp = last_yolo_msg; return tmp; }` My thinking is that in your version the mutex is released before `last_yolo_msg` is copied.

Comment: I think it is time for you to use a debugger and step through your code to find the place of your crash. There is not enough information in your code snippet to be suee, but I suspect : bounding_boxes[0] is accessing an unitialized or empty array. Also know that succesful compilation doesn't mean your program is correct (C++ doesn't hold your hand and assumes you know what you are doing)

Comment: @john no, the mutex is held until after return has completed